# python split function to read a string between two forward slashes

Tags: python, clearcase-automation

I am very new to python, i am trying to write a script which opens a file, read the file do some custom function for me and store it in project location. 
Meanwhile i am facing trouble to read the file line by line and find the string in between the two forward slashes. like in the example shown below i want the script to read the "string between the slashes".

"element / read_this_string /... "

I did go through some hints provided online, as in to use Regular expression or use split function. I found split() rather easy to implement.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this problem i am stuck with. I am sure its a simple one but i am wasting too much time on this.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: _"I found split() rather easy to implement."_ So you're saying you already have a solution for your problem, and the solution uses `split`, and the solution was easy? Just use that then. Or do you mean something else...?

Comment: @Kevin...problem is i am having trouble implementing the solution using the split()....i am not sure how to work around for the solution !!

Comment: @haifzhan .....This is what i have tried with "data = infile.read().split('element / /') , where 'infile' is the file created...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open a file in python, you can use python's with statement, which will handle file closing. and the for loop will take care of reading the file line by line.

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if len(line.split("/")) > 1:
            print(line.split("/")[1])
```

Comment: @slcjordan....thanks for ur help, but i am getting a syntaxError: Invalid syntax. for the line "print line.split("/")[1]"......not sure why !!

Comment: So I did somethink like this " file = line.split("/")[1]" , but this is throwing me an error saying "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: So that's probably because not every line has two slashes... See my edit

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a delimiter to split, to clean the spaces you can them use the strip method..

```
s = "element / read_this_string /... "

string_in_slashes = s.split('/')[1].strip()

string_in_slashes
Out[13]: 'read_this_string'
```